# Is it possible to access the character after matched position (&) in sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a text like:

`... - hi- 12-`

my desired output is to have a space between **alphanumeric** values that end with `-` :

`... - hi - 12 -`

notice that the first hyphen stayed at place since it's preceded by space - not alphanemuric.

also words like `multi-line` should not be modified.

**here's what I'm using**:

`echo " - hi- 12-" | sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]]-($|[^[:alnum:]])/ &/g'`

which outputs:

`" - h i- 1 2-"`

is there a way I could use `&+1` position?

Comment: `&` is the complete match, did you mean to use `\1` for just the first capture group instead? Also, the rule for "words like `multi-line` should not be modified", what is it exactly? Insert a blank if the hyphen is followed by a blank? Your current rule would insert a blank for `abc-.`, for example.

Comment: @BenjaminW. if the hyphen is surronded by alnum, nothing should be changed. Capture groups are the parts inside `(...)` right? I tried this : `s/([[:alnum:]])-($|[^[:alnum:]])/\1 - /g'` but it seems hacky to me.

Comment: You can't use `&+1` because we can never be sure there is any char at the position after the current match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you mean in general? Because here I'm matching an alnum which is followed by a hyphen. So it's certain there's a char after it.

Comment: No, the regex engine has no idea if there is a char after a match until it actually tries to do that.

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]])-($|[^[:alnum:]])/\1 -\2/g'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not very familiar with capture groups. Can you explain what `\2` does here?

Comment: Capturing groups allow access to parts of matched text. I posted an answer, please check and let know what is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]])-($|[^[:alnum:]])/\1 -\2/g' <<< " - hi- 12-"
#         ^-- Group1--^ ^-- Group 2 ---^
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/xw1Yps)

**Details**

- `([[:alnum:]])` - Capturing group #1: an alphanumeric char
- `-` - a hyphen
- `($|[^[:alnum:]])` - Capturing group #2: end of string or any char but alphanumeric.

In the RHS (replacement pattern), `\1` and `\2` placeholders (or numeric backreferences) refer to the text captured with the corresponding groups.